# Mary had a riddle lamb #1

Tags: riddle, rhyme

***"Mary had a riddle lamb, brain-tease was hard as stone!"***

Today Mary's lamb wants you to solve its riddle.

A white man plowing the dark soil
Silent oxen around him toil
A train whistle is near
What's said may disappear

**Half hint:**

> The lamb isn't involved, that's just the name of a series of riddle.

**Hint #1:**

> Caius Titus dixit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> CHALK.

*A white man plowing the dark soil*

> Chalk on a blackboard.

*Silent oxen around him toil*

> Silent pupils in a classroom, or students in a lecture hall, toiling to copy down what the chalk is writing on the board. **Intended explanation**: silent fingers gripping the chalk and toiling to move it.

*A train whistle is near*

> The whistle at the start and end of school sessions. **Intended explanation**: chalk screeching on a blackboard can sound like a train whistle.

*What's said may disappear*

> The writing on the board (what's 'said' by the chalk) gets rubbed out ('disappears') later. This was also **intended** to be a reference to the Latin proverb ["Verba volant, scripta manent"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verba_volant,_scripta_manent).

I got this by reading [the full poem alluded to in the title](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Had_a_Little_Lamb) and hunting for ideas in there.

Comment: Mary's Lamb followed her to the "answer" one day :-) Great Job !!!

Comment: No, but quite close!

Comment: Actually, extremely close, a couple of your explanations are correct.

Comment: @leoll2 I've edited - any joy?

Comment: Ahah nice one! Still close, but your previous answer was even closer!

Comment: @leoll2 Ah, I'd better undo my edit then! Is it some other kind of institution? School, workplace, prison, mental asylum, ... all pretty similar, right? ;-)

Comment: No institution, but something related.

Comment: Yep, one of those, now write a valid explanation for the 25 points prize!

Comment: @leoll2 I think I got it now; the only line I'm not completely certain of is the whistle line (why a *train* whistle?), but it does *seem* to fit.

Comment: Correct answer now! The silent oxen are actually fingers, the train whistle is the typical painful screech of chalk. The last sentence is basically "Scripta manent, verba volant", said by Caius Titus for the first time.

Comment: @leoll2 I've now edited to take account of these explanations. Nice riddle btw! The first line is the biggest giveaway; as we've seen, the rest can be made to fit the answer in a couple of ways.

Comment: I was inspired by 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veronese_Riddle
I don't think anyone of you knew this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it fits as well as the other close answer, but maybe it's:

> Examination

*A white man plowing the dark soil*

> White exam paper, with black writing

*Silent oxen around him toil*

> Silent students toiling at the exam

*A train whistle is near*

> The whistle to signal the end of the exam

*What's said may disappear*

> The only thing spoken is the invigilator announcing the remaining time left for the exam, which inevitably disappears.

Comment: Nice try, but not what I was thinking!

Answer (score 1):

what about:

> eraser ?

A white man plowing the dark soil
Silent oxen around him toil

> the erasers are usually white rubber thingy and the oxen are the letters written

A train whistle is near
What's said may disappear

> what is written will be erased, no idea if the whistle plays an important role or just makes the riddle dramatic :)

Comment: I didn't see your answer when I posted mine! We've got a lot of the same ideas, but I think I've cracked it since the whistle and the title fit my answer too.

Comment: yes indeed.. good work @randal'thor !

Comment: Close, but not my answer!