# Mary had a riddle lamb #2

Tags: riddle, rhyme

***"Mary had a riddle lamb, brain-tease was hard as stone!"***

Scratch that thing,
It's the name of this being!

Not only a furry creature,
But the sweetest of nature!

Damn horrible intruder,
Get out of my computer!

Surely ain't emblem of pluck,
At most it may bring luck!

> *Riddle Lamb #1 **[here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11100/mary-had-a-riddle-lamb-1)***:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought the answer was

> Horse

Doesn't seem to match every line though

Scratch that thing,
It's the name of this being!

Not only a furry creature,
But the sweetest of nature!

> Horses have sweet natures

Damn horrible intruder,
Get out of my computer!

> Trojan horse

Surely ain't emblem of pluck,
At most it may bring luck!

> Lucky horse shoe

---

**guess 2**

> Rabbit

Scratch that thing,
It's the name of this being!

> Rabbits scratch, and some are called Scratch

Not only a furry creature,
But the sweetest of nature!

> Rabbits are sweet natured

Damn horrible intruder,
Get out of my computer!

> "Bunnie" http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Huang

Surely ain't emblem of pluck,
At most it may bring luck!

> Rabbits foot

Comment: I like it, but not the correct answer!

Comment: I also though about rabbits, but can't think of a computer intruder that's based on rabbits

Comment: @leoll2 added my second guess

Comment: Rabbit is correct! About interpretation, a couple of lines aren't as intended:
"Scratch that thing"="Rub it", which sounds like rabbit.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb is also known as rabbit!

Comment: dern i guess i type too slow

Answer (score 4):

I think it is

> A hare (similar to a rabbit)

Scratch that thing,
It's the name of this being!

> I guess it's common to scratch you head (hair -- hare)

Not only a furry creature,
But the sweetest of nature!

> Rabbits (hares) are furry and sweet

Damn horrible intruder,
Get out of my computer!

> Ever get a piece of hair stuck in your keyboard? or even in your pc?

Surely ain't emblem of pluck,
At most it may bring luck!

> pluck is something you can do to hair (play on words- hare), and rabbit's feet are lucky

Answer (score 1):

It's

> a CAT (again!)

*Scratch that thing,

 It's the name of this being!*

> A cat can scratch, or you might scratch one behind its ears. The letters C, A, T are contained in the word "scratch".

*Not only a furry creature,

 But the sweetest of nature!*

> Cats are furry creatures, and (at least some of them) have sweet natures.

*Damn horrible intruder,

 Get out of my computer!*

> Is there a type of virus called a cat?

*Surely ain't emblem of pluck,*

> A lion is sometimes used as a symbol of courage.

*At most it may bring luck!*

> Cats, especially black ones, are seen as bringing luck.

Maybe the title should have contained the word "pray"? ;-)

> [You will have to pray!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4615/you-will-have-to-pray)
>  [riddle - pray you can find the word!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5141/riddle-pray-you-can-find-the-word)
>  [Riddle... pray that this is the last one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5428/riddle-pray-that-this-is-the-last-one)

Comment: Good answer! 
I've just found in Google that black cats bring luck in some cultures (in mine they bring bad luck). 
By the way, I'm sorry but "cat" isn't the right answer!

Comment: @leoll2 The other idea I had was "horse" - would that be worth posting too?

Comment: Looks like someone was faster...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a BEE

Scratch that thing, It's the name of this being!

> to me would be a bee sting

Not only a furry creature, But the sweetest of nature!

> bees are a hairy creature and collect pollen from nature

Damn horrible intruder, Get out of my computer!

> can't answer this one

Surely ain't emblem of pluck

> could be plucking the stinger out

At most it may bring luck!

> in some countries around the world a bee sting is thought to bring good luck.....

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Please could you explain how this answer fits the riddle?

Comment: Scratch that thing,
It's the name of this being! - to me would be a bee sting :  Not only a furry creature,
But the sweetest of nature! - bees are a hairy creature and collect pollen from nature: Damn horrible intruder,
Get out of my computer! - can't answer this one: Surely ain't emblem of pluck, - could be plucking the stinger out : At most it may bring luck! - in some countries around the world a bee sting is thought to bring good luck.....